# PHP "random include" Code Not Working as Expected

Tags: php, random, include

I have this php code that should take all the php files in a directory that are newer than x days and have one of them chosen randomly for inclusion. The code works perfectly with this part left out:
    && filectime( $path.$file ) > time()-60*60*24*4

When I do have that part in the code it gives me these 2 errors BUT ONLY if NONE of the files meet the requirments. If at least one file meets the requirments it functions normaly:

```
Warning: include() [function.include]: Filename cannot be empty in FILEPATH/THISFILE.php on line 15
```

```
Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening '' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php-5.2.17/lib/php') in FILEPATH/THISFILE.php on line 15
```

I am not sure why that one "condition" is creating this problem. If no file meets the condition without the "time if" it still functions normaly. 
Does anyone know what is going on? Thank, Luc 
Here is the code with line 15 marked:

```
<?php
$files = array();
$path = "nasa-news/";
if( $handle = opendir( $path ) ) 
{        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) 
    {                if( $file != "." && $file != ".." && !is_dir( $path.$file ) && strpos($file, '.php',1) && filectime( $path.$file ) > time()-60*60*24*4 ) // Only if it is a .php file that is less than 4 days old.
    {                                   $files[] = $path.$file;                                
    }                
}        
// You need to populate the $files variable before you count it;)        
$file = $files[ rand( 0, count( $files )-1 ) ];        
// Now we can include it!        
include ("$file");
}
else 
{        
print "<br />No New News Found!"; // If no files meet the conditions this should print.
LINE 15 }       
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
$file = $files[ rand( 0, count( $files )-1 ) ];
```

When your array has no elements, this will cause an undefined index. Thus, `$file` is empty...

So you need to check whether your array is empty first.
Btw, you could try shuffling the array and taking the first element. Much simpler:

```
if (count($files))
{
    shuffle($files);
    $file = $files[0]; // your random element, have some fun with it!
}
else
{
    // Handle edge case
}
```

Comment: And now made this a real answer.

Comment: Thanks, your help helped me! That was a great idea to use shuffle instead of random. This was the first time I used stack overflow... and I had a good experience with it.